# Необходимо открыть файл json не зная его полного названия

Tags: python

Имеется папка data, где содержатся файлы в формате json с подобными названиями - 61237712_129982.json

Проблема заключается в том, что первый набор цифр, а именно 61237712 программе известен, а второй набор будет генерироваться случайно, и программе не будет известен. Каким образом я могу открыть данный файл?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433177/open-file-knowing-only-a-part-of-its-name

Comment: Перебирайте файлы-кандидаты через `glob.glob` или через через `os.walk`.